# Joomla captcha plugin failing to load

Tags: php, plugins, configuration, joomla, captcha

I've been given a joomla project to upgrade from Joomla 3 to 4. After many hiccups, I got a local instance of the old site working in MAMP, but the login and reset password feature isn't working. I get an error, "Captcha plugin not set or not found. Please contact a site administrator". Since I can't log in, I can't use the interface to install plugins or check configuration. I found the entries for "captcha" plugins in the "_extensions" table and changed the "enabled" field value to 0, but there's no difference. I'm desperate to get this working as it's holding everything back. Any ideas on how to fix the plugins issue?